# Passing parameter as Dictionary<string,string[]> with jquery getJSON method

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass multiple parameters using `$.getJSON` function. To do this I have created a `DTO` class that defined as below.

```
public class MyDTO
{
    public string IncludeProperties {get; set;}
    public Dictionary<string,string[]> Predicate {get; set;}
}
```

Here is my web api functon:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("FindAll")]
public IEnumerable <Hotel> FindAll([FromUri] MyDTO predicateDTO) {
  return DataStore.FindAll <Hotel> (predicateDTO.IncludeProperties, PredicateHelper.ConvertStringToLambda <Hotel> (predicateDTO.Predicate));
}
```

[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery):

```
var uri = '/api/Hotel/FindAll';
var predicate = {
  "HotelName": ["HOtel", "==", ""],
  "PaymentStatus": ["True", "==", "AND"]
}
var data = {
  IncludeProperties: ["HotelDetails", "HotelDetails.HotelMainPhotos"],
  Predicate: predicate
}
busyIndicatorVisibility(true);
$('#ModalOtel .modal-body').find(".media").remove();
$.getJSON(uri, {
    predicateDTO: data
  }).done( //TODO something)
```

When I call my function `IncludeProperties` has items but `Predicate` property is `null`. 
How can I pass `Dictionary<string,string[]>` as parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my method.

```
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("FindAll")]
 public IEnumerable<Hotel> FindAll(string[] IncludeProperties, string Predicate)
 {
    Dictionary<string,string[]> predicateAsDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string[]>>(predicateString)
    return DataStore.FindAll<Hotel>(IncludeProperties, predicateAsDictionary);
 }
```

`getJson` method does not convert `var predicate` object that is defined in [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) to `Dictionary` However when I send this object using `JSON.stringify(predicate)` I can deserialize that string to a `Dictionary`

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to show you an idea to start with the solution.

You will need to update your MyDTO Model like this:

```
    public class Predicate
    {
        public string[] HotelName { get; set; } // In javascript can hold: ["HOtel", "==", ""] 
        public string[] PaymentStatus { get; set; }
    }
    public class MyDTO
    {
        public string[] IncludeProperties { get; set; }
        public Predicate predicate { get; set; }
    }
```

In your jQuery function, you will need to replace your $.getJSON for $.ajax(), like this:

```
var predicate = {
    "HotelName": ["HOtel", "==", ""],
    "PaymentStatus": ["True", "==", "AND"]
};
var data = {
    IncludeProperties: ["HotelDetails", "HotelDetails.HotelMainPhotos"],
    Predicate: predicate
};

$.ajax(
{
    url: uri,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data), // To convert javascript objects in json strings.
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // To send json objects to the web api controller.
    beforeSend: function ()
    {
        console.log("Wait a minute...");
    },
    success: function (response)
    {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

The $.ajax() function will send your json data with this format:

```
{
    "IncludeProperties": [
        "HotelDetails",
        "HotelDetails.HotelMainPhotos"
    ],
    "Predicate": {
        "HotelName": [
            "HOtel",
            "==",
            ""
        ],
        "PaymentStatus": [
            "True",
            "==",
            "AND"
        ]
    }
}
```

In your web api controller, try to change to this:

```
public string FindAll(MyDTO predicateDTO) // This contains all model with submodels.
{
     string result = "";
     // You can have access to predicateDTO instance with the current data;
     // predicateDTO.predicate.HotelName...
     return result;
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
My key values are changed depends on objects that I have created in c# so I must create a `Predicate` class for every object. I think It is not useful in this situation.